# GIMP How to edit deselected Path

Tags: gimp, image-editing

I've already finished my path but in the end I saw one flaw that need to be edited. How to display the `tiny white button / points` that allows me to edit the path?

***Refer red circled flaw below, there are a few `points` somewhere there, how to call it out? Thanks.**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure a mask is a path after creating it.

Answer (score 2):

- Open the Paths list (`Windows>Dockable dialogs>Paths`)
- Make the path visible by clicling on the eye icon (works same as in the Layers list)
- Start the Path editor tool
- Click on the path line in the image window, the path should become editable (if you click too far from the line, you create a new path).

Answer (score 1):

You'll not only need to select the path in the paths dialog, and click on it to make it visible, and edit with the Paths Tool, as per @xenoid's instructions, but you will also need to make a new mask from the path after you've edited it. Deselect the selection by pressing Shift+CTRL+A (Select None). Delete the layer mask by right clicking it in the layers panel and choose Delete Layer Mask. Then after you have edited the path, turn it into a selection again, and add another layer mask.

The moral to this story is to make sure your path is right before you turn it into a selection and apply the layer mask. Examine it closely by zooming in.

It would be great if GIMP had live vector masks you could edit (like Photoshop), but it doesn't have this feature yet.  However, if the layer mask is not much wrong, you can also edit it directly by clicking on the layer mask thumbnail in the layers panel, and edit the mask using the Paint Brush tool to paint on the mask. Paint in black for full transparency, and white for full opacity.